# Laravel 5.6 with Bootstrap Multiselect styling

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-4

Right now the logic for this multiselect works. The issue is, I can only select items right next to each other (like below photo).
[image]

What I want it to look like is something like this.

[image]

Posted below is the code for my blade template:

```
    {{Form::label('server_id', 'Server')}}   
        <select name="server_ids[]" id="server_id" class="form-control form-control-md" multiple="multiple">
            @foreach($servers as $key => $name)
                <option value="{{$key}}">{{$name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to either do this in bootstrap or a package made for laravel that I can achieve similar results to?

Comment: have you tried control-clicking?

Comment: Is this just an interface issue? I know you can `CMD + CLICK` options (on Mac) to select multiple but not in a row. If you use `SHIFT + CLICK` you'll select all options from the first to the last that you choose.

Comment: ctrl+click works but for a user would be pretty inconvenient

Comment: Not really... `<select ... multiple` elements should behave the same regardless of framework used to style it. Any power-user of HTML should know how to use a select for this. Otherwise, this is a UX/UI issue; consider adding a tooltip "Use control click to select multiple" or something similar.

Comment: Good call @TimLewis.. I just talked it over with my manger and he said leave it with ctrl+click because only IT will have access to this and they should have enough technical skills to press 2 buttons.

Comment: Haha yes, I would hope so. Since you're using Bootstrap, you could use a help `glyphicon` with `tooltip` or a `popover` that has that message, or a `help-block`, etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is by using a plugin like [select2](https://select2.org/) or to write your own.